# Understanding Class inheritance to DRY up some code

Tags: python, cloudant

I am using the `cloudant` python library to connect to my cloudant account.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import cloudant


class WorkflowsCloudant(cloudant.Account):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WorkflowsCloudant, self).__init__(settings.COUCH_DB_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                                                auth=(settings.COUCH_PUBLIC_KEY,
                                                      settings.COUCH_PRIVATE_KEY))

    @blueprint.route('/<workflow_id>')
    def get_single_workflow(account_id, workflow_id):
        account = WorkflowsCloudant()
        db = account.database(settings.COUCH_DB_NAME)
        doc = db.document(workflow_id)
        resp = doc.get().json()

        if resp['account_id'] != account_id:
            return error_helpers.forbidden('Invalid Account')

        return jsonify(resp)
```

This `Flask` controller will have `CRUD` operations inside of it, but with the current implementation, I will have to set the `account` and `db` variables in each method before performing operations on the document I want to view/manipulate. How can I clean up (or DRY up) my code so that I only have to call to my main `WorkflowsCloudant` class?

Comment: Can you please state this as a question?

Comment: @jrennie I have cleaned it up

Comment: Can you create `account`, `db`, and `doc` within `WorkflowsCouldant.__init__`, and make `doc` a public field?

Comment: @jrennie can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `cloudant`, so I may be totally off base, but I believe this answers your question:

Delete the `account`, `db`, and `doc` lines from `get_single_workflow`.

Add the following lines to `__init__`:

```
db = account.database(settings.COUCH_DB_NAME)
self.doc = db.document(workflow_id)
```

Change the `resp` line in `get_single_workflow` to:

```
resp = WorkflowsCloudant().doc.get().json()
```